# How to inherit and use another class at the same time?

Tags: c#

another newbie question in C#.
  i.e. I have:

```
namespace MyFunctions{
    public class main{

      public void SHOW(string str){
         MessageBox.Show(str);
      }

    }
}
```

however, I want to import that lib (enrich) into another class,like:

```
namespace xyz{
    use MyFunctions.main; // <--- something like that ??
    public class A : ProgramBase{

        public void message(){
            SHOW("Hi");
        }
    }

}
```

How to make it as I can make those class methods like a native methods (to call easily) in another class?  (because multiple inheritance is not allowed... I dont like `interface` because then i have to write the methods on twice place).

Comment: you can use class library in C#

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/creating-class-library-in-visual-C-Sharp/

Comment: If you want to inherit from class 'main' with class 'B' then it would be 'public class A : main' and the 'use' statement should be 'using MyFunctions;' But you probably want to read up on the basics of C# some I think.

Comment: Possible solution for me was to use `Partial` classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do multiple inheritance in C#, but you need to use these methods as native ones, I can think of two ways:

1. Use as external library (or class by just creating new instance and use the methods inside your class, which will have the same exact method names and you can force that by inheriting from interfaces containing that method signature).
2. Use as extensions:

   ```
   namespace MyFunctions{
       public static class main{

         public static void SHOW(this A src, string str){
           MessageBox.Show(str);
         }
       }
   }
   ```

   Or if your method `SHOW` doesn't care about the type that call it you can make it generic:

   ```
   public static void SHOW<T>(this T src, string str){
      MessageBox.Show(str);
   }
   ```

Comment: @T.Todua external library is same class library in C# i share link in comment

Comment: If you mean a reference to a compiled assembly have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx (if it's a 3rd party assembly make suer you read up on NuGet)

Comment: It depends  , if your class is in another project use it either by referencing the project directly or by referencing the dll that's compiled ...

Comment: If the class is in same project then use it directly

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but you can use delegate :

```
public delegate void show(string s);
namespace MyFunctions
{
    public class main
    {
        public static void SHOW(string str)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
    }
}

namespace xyz
{
    //use MyFunctions.main; // <--- something like that ??
    public class A : ProgramBase
    {
        public static event show show_event = MyFunctions.main.SHOW; // use delegate
        public void message()
        {
            show_event("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```